# Identificar elementos que se repetem dentro de um array bidimensional

Tags: ruby

Em um array

```
a = [[1,"José"],[2,"Pedro"],[3,"Maria"],[4,"Lauro"],[2,"Pedro"],
     [5,"Léo"],[1,"José"],[6,"Caio"]]
```

como obter um novo array b que mostre as posições dos índices com os arrays que se repetem(iguais)?, nesse caso o array b ficaria assim:

```
b = [[0,6],[1,4]]
```

Consegui fazendo um clone do array comparando cada posição, mas ficou de certa forma demorado e tem também as posições originais que são incluídas no array b tornando-o o mesmo array com as posíções que são iguais, então não ficou legal.

Comment: Mostre o que você fez.

Comment: Assim dá certo, estou tentando tirar o vício do for para usar o each que é mais elegante e funcional, já alterei vários códigos substituindo o for, principalmente por causa dos índices que me perco muito com eles.
'a1 = a.clone

b = Array.new
cont_i = 0
for i in (0..a.length-1)
  for j in ((i+1)..a1.length-1)
    if a[i] == a1[j]
      b[cont_i] = [i, j]
      cont_i += 1
    end
  end
end
'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem muitas formas para se fazer isto, mas de acordo com este [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/rklemme/2463600), esta é a solução mais eficiente:

```
a = [[1,"José"],[2,"Pedro"],[3,"Maria"],[4,"Lauro"],[2,"Pedro"],
 [5,"Léo"],[1,"José"],[6,"Caio"]]

dups = {}
a.each_with_index do |val, idx|
    (dups[val] ||= []) << idx
end
dups.delete_if {|k,v| v.size == 1}

# => {[1, "José"]=>[0, 6], [2, "Pedro"]=>[1, 4]}
```

Comment: Gostei do uso de hash, sem dúvida existem diversas formas de se fazer isso, vai da experiência de cada programador, o que não é meu caso..rsrs, mas vou aprendendo com esses mestres daqui.

Comment: Rafael, fiquei impressionado com a velocidade com que o resultado aparece, nos testes que eu fiz, em muitas execuções não chega ao tempo de 1(um) segundo, é instantâneo, já na minha solução(aff) e na do Guilherme, chega a 9 segundos, porque isso ocorre? é o fato de usar hash? alguém saberia me explicar? Obs: O array que estou testando tem 3501 arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,"José"],[2,"Pedro"],[3,"Maria"],[4,"Lauro"],[2,"Pedro"],
     [5,"Léo"],[1,"José"],[6,"Caio"]]
```

Passeando pelos métodos das arrays podemos montar o seguinte:

`each_index` itera sobre os índices. Para saber quais índices são iguais a um dado elemento podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
a.each_index.select{|i| a[i] == [1,"José"] }
# => [0, 6]
```

Se quer aplicar isso a todos os elementos da array, use primeiro `uniq` para gerar uma lista sem repetições e então o `map` para transformar cada elemento nos seus índices:

```
a.uniq.map{|el| a.each_index.select{|i| a[i] == el } }
# => [[0, 6], [1, 4], [2], [3], [5], [7]]
```

Se você quer mostrar apenas os que existem alguma repetição, rejeite no final tudo que só existe uma vez:

```
a.uniq.map{|el| a.each_index.select{|i| a[i] == el } }.reject{|is| is.size == 1 }
# => [[0, 6], [1, 4]]
```

Elegante, não?

Comment: E muito elegante..legal é esse aninhamento de métodos que preciso focar mais.